# Validator creates multiple messages - unecessary "Assertion Failed" message

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I have a JSF validator that checks on the value in multiple fields (just before saving):

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
        <a:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
            <h:message for="#{bookDtlView.detailBean.editFormId}" 
                    styleClass="message" 
                    errorClass="errormsg" 
                    infoClass="infomsg" 
                    warnClass="warnmsg"/>
        </a:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

...

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean validateBean() {
    boolean valid = true;
    try {
        BookDtlView dtlv = (BookDtlView) getComponentInstance(BookDtlView.class);
        BookDtl dtl = dtlv.getDetailBean();

        Book book = dtl.getInstance();

        if (book.hasEnumerationStyledCode() && (book.getCode() != null)) {
            if (!topic.getCode().matches("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*$")) {
                valid = false;
                getStatusMessages().add(Severity.ERROR, "Codes must begin with a capital letter and contain only capital letters, numbers, and underscores.");
            }
        }

        if (valid) {
            if (dtl.isDuplicate()) {
                valid = false;
                getStatusMessages().add(Severity.ERROR, "The selected code value is already in use.");
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        valid = false;
        error(e);
        getStatusMessages().add(Severity.ERROR, "UNEXPECTED ERROR. Please navigate away from this page and report the problem.");
    }

    return valid;
}
```

When the user incorrectly enters the code the error is show properly "Codes must begin with a capital letter and contain only capital letters, numbers, and underscores." But an error is also shown on the console:

INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=cteForm:j_id14[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Assertion Failed), detail=(Assertion Failed)]

When I switch the JSF code `<h:message>` to `<h:messages>`  The console stuff goes away, but an Assertion Failed message is added to the list of displayed errors.

How do I get rid of the Assertion Failed from the messages?

Comment: You seem to be mixing "JSR303 bean validation" with "JSF validation". The desired message should go in `@AssertTrue` annotation, not being manually added as faces message.

Comment: @BalusC Though I have multiple complex checks in this validator, how would I break it out?